# Python: calling stop on mock patch class decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

The Mock [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#applying-the-same-patch-to-every-test-method) describes a simple and elegant way of applying patches to all of the tests method inside a `TestCase`:

```
@patch('foo.bar')
@patch('foo.baz')
@patch('foo.quux')
@patch('foo.narf')
class FooTest(TestCase):

    def test_foo(self, bar, baz, quux, narf):
        """ foo """
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

However, one issue I've encountered with this method is that if I'd like to call stop() on one of the patches inside one of the test methods, there doesn't appear to be anyway of getting a reference to the patcher object -- the only thing that is passed into the method is the mock objects, in this case `bar`, `baz`, `quux`, `narf`.

The only way I've found to solve this problem is to move to the pattern described in the Mock docs where the patchers are instantiated and started inside the `setUp` method of the `TestCase` and stopped inside the `tearDown` method. This fits my purpose, but adds a lot of extra boilerplate and isn't as elegant as the class decorator approach.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1**

Say you want to temporarily restore `foo.narf` in a method. `foo.narf` is, in the context of the decorated function, a `MagicMock` object. This object has a `_mock_wraps` attribute which will be invoked when the mock is called! So at the top of your module, `_narf = foo.narf`, and in your test case, `foo.narf._mock_wraps = _narf`.

The catch is that this will only pass through to the real function, not actually swap it back, which means that some test cases will fail (e.g. if they rely on the function object actually being "itself"). And if your mock has other attributes, that *could* interfere (I haven't tested much) because the passthrough call to `_mock_wraps()` comes at the bottom of a method that first considers the other properties of the mock.

**2**

The `patch()` decorator involves each `patcher` (separate copies per method) being added to a list called `patchings` which is a field of the method itself. I.e. you can access this list as `self.test_foo.patchings`, and go through to find the one you want.

However, `start()` and `stop()` are not actually called when you use `patch()` as a decorator, and the behavior gets tricky once you start reaching in and changing it. So I wrote this context manager.

```
class unpatch:
    def __init__(self, name, method):
        compare = patch(name)
        self.patcher = next((
            p for p in method.patchings
            if p.target == compare.getter()
            and p.attribute == compare.attribute
        ), None)
        if self.patcher is None:
            raise ValueError(name)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.patcher.__exit__()

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        self.patcher.__enter__()
```

Inside your test case, you use it like this:

```
with unpatch('foo.narf', self.test_foo):
    foo.narf()
```

Disclaimer: this is hacks.